# After installing ubuntu to dual boot with Windows 7, can't boot to windows

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows

Here's a link to the summary generated by boot-repair: http://paste2.org/aXKNKUvf

I have both a hard drive and SSD. In GRUB, the options I see to boot are:

```
Ubuntu
Advanced options for Ubuntu
efi/Windows/System32/winload.efi
efi/Windows/System32/winresume.efi
```

Neither of the Windows options work. Is there anything I can do?

Updated boot-repair summary: http://paste2.org/OnjgC5C4
I ran boot-repair for recommended fixes, and now I have many more boot options:

```
Ubuntu
Advanced options for Ubuntu
Windows UEFI bootmgfw.efi
Windows Boot UEFI loader
EFI/ubuntu/MokManager.efi
Windows UEFI bootmgfw.efi sdb1
Windows Boot UEFI loader sdb1
EFI/ubuntu/MokManager.efi sdb1
efi/EFI/Boot/bkpbootx64.efi
efi/EFI/ubuntu/MokManager.efi
Windows Boot Manager (on /dev/sda1)
```

None of the Windows options work. Several of the Windows options bring me to a loading screen which says "Windows is loading files", but then I end up back in GRUB.

Comment: Why do you have syslinux as well as grub?

Comment: I don't know actually. I did a bunch of stuff with this setup maybe 4 years ago, and haven't messed with it much since. What I had working until today was Ubuntu and Windows both booting off of /dev/sdb (my SSD) so I don't know how much the one on /dev/sda matters.

Comment: My windows partition is on /dev/sdb1 FWIW